# Getting arguments sent to my bundled java app

Tags: java, macos, arguments

I built a simple text editor using Java SWT and packed the classes into a jar file.
From this jar file I made an app using Oracle's AppBundler ant task. That works very well so far.
My problem is now that I can't get any arguments semt to my program.

Let's say that I want to open a text file. So I select the file in the Finder app, right click it and choose "open with". Then I browse to my text editor and expecting to get the text file to open.
My app starts correctly but the args array (parameter of the main method) is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fork of appbundler: https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler

I had the same issue and contributed a fix for it there:
https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/issues/2/command-line-parameter-passing